# how to map virtual memory to physical memory

Tags: memory, virtualization

Is there a way to map virtual memory to physical memory. I need to be able to do this in order to write a memory diagnostic program. The linux version is 2.6.36.4

Comment: Not reliably. The mapping can change at any time. By the time you have the information, it can already be obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

No.

If you are writing a memory diagnostic routine you really need to stick your fingers into the kernel space to do it - it's pretty much impossible to do in user space (the VM space is relocatable and can be anywhere in physical memory - or not in physical memory at all).

For that matter there's no reason for you to write a memory diagnostic program - [this is a solved problem](http://www.memtest.org) and the tools that have been written (and tested over many years) *will* be superior to your first-attempt solution, so you should use them.